# Caching. Browser vs Rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am reading the docs and I came across this code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def competing_price
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/competing_price", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      Competitor::API.find_price(id)
    end
  end
end
```

This is supposed to be an example of low-level caching (caching a value or query result). So I assume this cache is something that occurs server side. It expires in 12 hours. So any time the competing_price is called, whether or not it's from a user of the API or for internal use, the cached result is delivered from and this cache exists server side in the actual Rails app right?

What kinds of things are stored browser side? What does Chrome actually store in its cache? Javascript files? HTML files? Images?

What about on a proxy server like on Akamai?

Comment: "Javascript files? HTML files? Images?" - yes, all the files/content your app serves can (and likely will) be cached by the browser (or somewhere along the way  by proxy/proxies). What's the question, again?

Comment: What are the different things a server caches and a browser caches? Are they used differently? What gets stored in each typically?

Comment: The server should cache things heavy to load/compute that does not really change in a given period of time (like Stackoverflow's reputation ranking which is not computed at each time a user goes to the ranking page). The browser should cache things received by the server that does not changes in a period of time (like a banner image, Javascript files, logos, etc).

Comment: @MrYoshiji want to make this your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The **server should cache** things heavy to load/compute that does not really change in a given period of time. (show page of a product for example, static headers/footers, statistics to be recomputed every X minutes, etc).
- The **browser should cache** things received by the server that does not changes in a period of time (like a banner image, Javascript files, logos, etc).